# ASP.NET Core JwtBearerIdentity doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

After sending a header to api method it throws 401 error for me. I don't understand why. Here is my configuration.

**API controller**

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class AdminApiController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAdminService _adminService;

    public AdminApiController(IAdminService adminService)
    {
        _adminService = adminService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [Route("/api/rooms/add")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddRoom([FromBody]QuestRoomDto room)
    {
        return Ok(await _adminService.AddRoom(room));
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
services.AddIdentity<Customer, CustomerRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CustomerDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        //Configure Jwt authentication
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.SaveToken = true;
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                ValidAudience = configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtKey"])),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero 
            };
        });
```

I have two roles(Admin / User) this method not works even if I set it to any authorized person.

Comment: how does your header look like?

Comment: I send header with Postman - "Bearer {token}"

Comment: A 401 is a result of authorization failing.  It usually indicates the token is expired or invalid or in this case does not contain a role claim for Admin role.  You're not defining the `RoleClaimType` in `TokenValidationParameters` so that's probably a good place to start.